# Multiplication of several vectors

Tags: r, loops, vector, vector-multiplication

I have 10 vectors (v_1 to v_10) and I need all of them multiplied with another vector v_mult (i.e. v_1*v_mult, v_2*v_mult etc.). How to I solve this problem within a for-loop? Im stuck to the loop-solution (which I do not find) because it is part of a larger analysis.

```
v_10<-c(2, 3, 5, 8)
v_20<-c(3, 9, 0, 1)
v_30<-c(15, 9, 6, 0)
v_40<-c(4, 9, 6, 1)
v_50<-c(1, 7, 3, 9)
v_60<-c(5, 9, 5, 1)
v_70<-c(5, 8, 2, 6)
v_80<-c(5, 8, 1, 6)
v_90<-c(5, 0, 1, 6)
v_10<-c(2, 8, 1, 0)

v_mult<-c(8, 5, 1, 9)
```

Comment: You could start by adding putting v_1 to v_10 in a list. Then you could use a loop or lapply.

Comment: Those vectors should probably not only be in a list, but `cbind`ed into a matrix. Then you could do `m * v_mult`.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself having such variables, take a step back and think of a more appropriate data structure. Numbering your variables is **never** appropriate. In this case, a matrix is appropriate. In other cases, a nested list structure might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those vectors should be all together in a matrix:

```
vlist <- mget(ls(pattern = "v_[[:digit:]*]"))
m <- do.call(cbind, vlist)
m * v_mult
#     v_10 v_20 v_30 v_40 v_50 v_60 v_70 v_80 v_90
#[1,]   16   24  120   32    8   40   40   40   40
#[2,]   40   45   45   45   35   45   40   40    0
#[3,]    1    0    6    6    3    5    2    1    1
#[4,]    0    9    0    9   81    9   54   54   54
```

You can of course extract each vector from the matrix using column subsetting, e.g., `m[, "v_10"]` or `m[, 1]`.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the solution, I was looking for - especially because it is very simple and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

We can get all the vector objects in a `list` using `mget`and multiply each element of the `list` with 'v_mult' using `Map`.

```
Map('*',mget(paste('v', seq(10, 100, by=10), sep="_")), list(v_mult))
```

---

Or use `set` from `data.table` which would be very fast as it doesn't have the `.[data.table` overhead.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(mget(paste('v', seq(10, 100, by=10), sep="_")))
for(j in seq_along(DT)){
  set(DT, i=NULL, j= j, value= DT[[j]]*v_mult)
}
```